# An interesting puzzle from Jiří Matoušek's book

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

There is an interesting puzzle from Jiří Matoušek's book *Invitation to Discrete Mathematics*, problem **1.2.8**, which confused me lots of time.

> Divide the following figure into $7$ parts, all of them congruent (they only differ by translation, rotation, and possibly by a mirror reflection). All the bounding segments in the figure have length $1$, and the angles are $90$, $120$, and $150$ degrees.
>   [image]

Comment: Is there an answer in this book ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did I miss anything from the question ?

[image]

Comment: That was my solution, too.